# how can I make perl wait until a command finishes before moving on with the rest of a for loop

Tags: perl

I have the follow script (just an excerpt, the other parts are not relevant):

```
@output = $con->cmd("show module | grep ignore-case \"Supervisor Module\" | cut -d \" \" -f 1");

for (@output[1 .. $#output]) {
    print "******* Supervisor Slot $_ *******\n";
    @suboutput = $con->cmd("slot $_ quoted 'show system internal raid'");
    print "@suboutput";
    print "\n";
}
```

I keep running into an issue where the script will get to the @suboutput line and then appear to move on to the other lines in the script without allowing the @suboutput line to complete. This results in the @suboutput array being cut short when I go to print it.

Is there a way to make the script wait for the command to complete prior to moving on to the rest of the script? I was thinking about using a sleep command, although I was not sure if there was a more concrete/foolproof way to make the script wait.

Another Idea I had was to make the script wait until the suboutput array contains an exact line "somehostname#" (no other text after the #, just somehostname#). This line will appear whenever the @suboutput line command is finished executing, see below to see what I am talking about:

```
somehostname# slot 5 quoted "show system internal raid"
RAID data from CMOS = 0x61 0xb7
RAID data from driver disks 0 bad 0 name
Current RAID status info:
Bootflash: /dev/sdb
Mirrorflash: /bin/cat: /var/log/boot_node_mirror: No such file or directory

Personalities : [raid1]
unused devices: <none>
Personalities : [raid1]
unused devices: <none>
/bin/cat: /var/log/raid_monitor.log: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: /var/log/raid_repair.log: No such file or directory
Current RAID status:
Bootup RAID status:
RAID Monitor log:
RAID repair log:
---------------------------------------------------
somehostname#
```

Once again I'm not sure if there would be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: What module are you using to run the command? / Can you show an entire piece of code that recreates the problem?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Hi, I'm using the following modules in this script:
use strict, warnings, Getopt::Long, Opsware::NAS::Connect. The perl script is being run from a server running HP Network Automation. The bulk of the script is just code that is used to connect to a proxy system that executes the code that is sent using $con->cmd. I did not include that part so that I could avoid any confusion. The $con->cmd part tells the proxy system to send a command to a network appliance, after which the output from the network appliance command is saved into suboutput.

Comment: What's the context for this?  Yes, you can wait (`sleep` for one -- see my answer), but that is immediately suspect of a need for a better approach -- for which on needs to see the context.

Comment: @zdim hello, sorry about taking so long to reply. We ended up getting HP involved (they are the publishers for the server software that this perl script runs in, HP Network Automation), and they provided a new driver (not perl related) and an updated perl module. This seems to have fixed the issue! It appears that the system was getting confused about when commands were completing execution (it was thinking that the slot x quoted .... command had completed, when in fact the command was still running. This was causing the output to get screwed up)

Comment: Ah, so it was something else entirely.  Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up fixing this problem by adding a new driver (non perl related) and an updated perl module.

We reached out to HP (publisher of the server software that executes this perl script) and they determined that the server & script were getting confused when executing the slot x quoted .... command and were prematurely cutting off the output. The updated files that HP provided have solved the issue by allowing HPNA and the perl script to properly determine when the command has actually finished executing.